# Get average by word in column

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with some text in Column 1 and a value in Column 2.
Column 1 can include multiple city names per row. Furthermore I have a list for eacht city name. Now I want to get the average value from Column 2 for each city that exists in my list.

```
Citylist = ["CityA","CityB"]
List1 = ["CityA Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, CityB","CityA Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet CityB"]
List2 = [1,2,3]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(List1, List2)), 
               columns =['Name', 'val'])
```

The result should be 1.5 for City A and 2.0 for City B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
avg_dict = {}
for city in Citylist:
    avg_dict[city] = df.loc[df['Name'].str.contains(city), 'val'].mean()
    print("Average for {}: {:.2f}".format(city, avg_dict[city]))
```

Answer (score 2):

First append the dataframe by cityName columns:

```
for cityName in ['CityA', 'CityB']:
    df.loc[:, cityName] = df.Name.apply(lambda x: cityName in x)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                      Name  val  CityA  CityB
0  CityA Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, CityB    1   True   True
1         CityA Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet    2   True  False
2         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet CityB    3  False   True
```

Now you can play with the resulting dataframe, for example:

```
for cityName in ['CityA', 'CityB']:
    print(cityName, np.mean(df[df[cityName]].val.tolist()))
```

Output:

```
CityA 1.5
CityB 2.0
```